# Find an item in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

A project in a coding class I'm taking asks students to finish the code for a password saver with a number of options and a menu. The part I'm having difficulty with is printing a password based on the website associated with it.

Passwords are saved in a list like so:

```
passwords = [["yahoo","XqffoZeo"],["google","CoIushujSetu"]]
```

What I'm attempting to do is find the address of an item within this list, inputted by the user, and print the item directly after it. The user will be asked to input a website and the following item in the list (the password) will be printed.

However, for testing purposes, I also need to check to see if a password for the website in question is in the "passwords" list.

```
if passwordToLookup in passwords:
            print(passwords.index(passwordToLookup))
```

For some reason, this always returns "False." Is this because the list I'm searching is encrypted? If so, how can I search in this list for a specific item? How could I print the second item in the list following the website?

Comment: Looks like you need to use a `dict`, and it's pretty trivial to transform this into a `dict`.

Comment: There's no encryption in this problem as you've presented it.

Comment: `[p for u, p in passwords if u == 'insert desired site here']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the list and check for the website:

```
for elem in passwords:
    if passwordToLookup in elem:
        print # elem[0] for the website or elem[1] for the password
```

not sure why you are trying to print the index but you can also use `passwords.index(elem)` if you want it.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution I needed!

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful by clicking the tick under the vote arrows on the left of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Using dictionaries**

```
# convert list into dictionary
d = dict(tuple(passwords))

try:
    d[passwordToLookup]
except KeyError:
    # what to do if no password available
else:
    # what to do if available
```

or use default get method of dictionary

```
return d.get(passwordToLookup, default=None)
```

**Without dictionaries**

```
values = list(zip(*passwords))

try:
    the_password = values[1][values[0].index(passwordToLookup)]
except ValueError:
    # what to do if no password available
else:
    # what to do if available
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are currently only looking in passwords which is a list of lists, but you need to iterate through passwords and test the individual lists within it. You could use something like this

```
passwords = [["yahoo","XqffoZeo"],["google","CoIushujSetu"]]

def getPasswordIndex():
    for list in passwords:
        if "CoIushujSetu" in list:
            return list.index("CoIushujSetu")
        else:
            print(False)

print(getPasswordIndex())

#returns False then 1 so it's the second item in the second list """

print(passwords[1][1])

#prints "CoIushujSetu"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a *dictionary* (`key: value` pairs) and your code will be as simple as this:

```
passwords = [["yahoo","XqffoZeo"],["google","CoIushujSetu"]]
pass_dict = dict(passwords)

site = input("Insert site: ")

if site in pass_dict:        # searching only in keys
    print(pass_dict[site])   # print value of that key
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't an option. The entire code isn't mine, as I explained. The list must stay the way it is.

Comment: @Yobby - No problem - I edited my answer to fulfill your need - I simply created a new dictionary from your nested list.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is iterate through the list something like this :

```
def ifPassExist():
    for password in passwords:
        if passwordToLookUp in password:
            return passwords.index(password)
```